# Fascinate Device Web view go back() method Issue

Tags: android

I am developing an app in android. In the app i am using a web view and i am saving the web view history.When user clicks on device back button i am loading the previous url(using web view goback() method) if web view history is not empty.It is working fine in all the devices except the Samsung Fascinate device. In this device web view goback() method is not working.
Any suggestions??

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to figure out how to do it

```
@override
public void onFormResubmission(WebView view, Message dontResend, Message resend)
{
resend.sendToTarget();
}
```

default behaviour of onFormResubmission is not to resubmit. `resend.sendToTarget();` changes that.

this will make ur hardware back button work if you have made some code to handle the hardware button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
mWebView.goBack();
return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```